# Django: error using get_or_create and unique_together

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating an API which list and save transactions. My `Transaction`s Model has a FK to a `Category` model. My goal when creating a `Transaction` is to also create the `Category` if the category is new.

The first time I create the transaction it successfully creates the new category and transaction. The next time I attempt the create a transaction with the existing category, I get an error that the category already exists. In my `Transaction` serializer I added a create method that should be using `get_or_create` for the category. However I'm still getting an error on my unique fields. My expectation is that it would be returning the existing `Category`.

It seems like it's throwing the error before it gets to the `create` method in the `Transaction` serializer before it has a chance to use `get_or_create`.

Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                          on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'owner')


class Transaction(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    payee = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                related_name='category',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = MoneyField(max_digits=19,
                        decimal_places=2,
                        default_currency='USD')
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True,
                                        auto_now_add=True)
    modified_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Serializers:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'owner', 'created_time', 'modified_time')


class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    balance = serializers.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2, max_digits=19, read_only=True)

    category = CategorySerializer(many=False, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ('id', 'date', 'payee', 'category',
                  'amount', 'balance', 'created_time', 'modified_time',
                  'is_cleared', 'paid_or_deposited')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        category_data = validated_data.pop('category')

        category, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(**category_data)

        transaction = Transaction.objects.create(category=category,
                                                 **validated_data)


        return transaction
```

POST:

```
{
"date": "2018-12-19",
"payee": "Test",
"category": {"owner": 1, "name": "TEST"},
"amount": "-134"
}
```

Error:

```
{
    "category": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "The fields name, owner must make a unique set."
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about not reaching your `create()` method.

This happens because `ModelSerializer` by default creates validators based on your model `Meta.unique_together` value: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer

Simplest way to disable this type of validators is to override [`get_unique_together_validators`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L1488-L1523) for your serializer:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'owner', 'created_time', 'modified_time')

    def get_unique_together_validators(self):
        return []
```

Another solution, which is cleaner is to override `Meta.validations` of your `CategorySerializer`*****:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'owner', 'created_time', 'modified_time')
        validators = []
```

***** <sub>be aware that this will disable serializer validators `unique_for_date`, `unique_for_month` and `unique_for_year` that come from model</sub>

Comment: This seems a little hacky. Is there a different way that I could go about changing my code to create a `Category` as part of creating a `Transaction` that wouldn't require me to override any methods like that?

Comment: @brewcrazy i supplied another solution which is cleaner than the first one.

Comment: What is the impact of either of these solutions if I try to create a Category directly? Do I lose my Category validation?

Comment: @brewcrazy Model validation will be untouched and work as it should.